# How to include file from the "library" fold in Zend

Tags: include, zend-framework

In Zend, inside the "Library" folder, I have a PHP file that I want to include in another file. How do I do that?! I cannot figure out the root to the library folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about study some documentation about Zend autoloading capabilities. There are plenty of options, how to autoload files,which contains php classes.

here you go http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.html

But if you want it plain and simple :

1. every zend application generated with zf tool should have defined APPLICATION_PATH constant, which is pointing into application folder. So you could use it for constructing absolute path to file
2. define namespace inside config, e.g. Autoloadernamespace[] = 'Custom_'. Then if you create inside library class file ./library/Custom/Object.php with class Custom_Object, Zend loader loads this file when you will be creating instance of Custom_Object class (or call static method)
3. RTFM, there are other things possible ...